# Допустимо ли "магазин с книгами" вместо "книжный магазин"?

Tags: управление, словосочетания

"книжный магазин" со связью управление. Допустим ли ответ "магазин с книгами"

Answer (score 2):

Это очень редкое словосочетание, подходит разве что для объявления о продаже книжного магазина *вместе* с товаром ("продам магазин с книгами") или для сообщения о пожаре (сгорел...). Проще сказать "**магазин книг**".